# Rhino Mocks - mocking a method whose return value changes (even when passed the same parameter) with multiple calls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm looking to find out how I can mock a method that returns a different value the second time it is called to the first time. For example, something like this:

```
public interface IApplicationLifetime
{
    int SecondsSinceStarted {get;}
}

[Test]
public void Expected_mock_behaviour()
{
    IApplicationLifetime mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IApplicationLifetime>();

    mock.Expect(m=>m.SecondsSinceStarted).Return(1).Repeat.Once();
    mock.Expect(m=>m.SecondsSinceStarted).Return(2).Repeat.Once();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, mock.SecondsSinceStarted);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, mock.SecondsSinceStarted);
}
```

Is there anything that makes this possible? Besides implementing a sub for the getter that implements a state machine?

Comment: Take a look at ordered and unordered mocks: http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%20Ordered%20and%20Unordered.ashx

Comment: Whats wrong with code you provided? `Repeat.Once()` should work

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The first call to m.SecondsSinceStarted returns 2, not 1 as expected

Comment: @AlexC can you provide real test code? Because `Repeat.Once()` will return 1 during first call

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The code above is real. If I run it with the latest build of RhinoMocks (after replacing m.SecondsSinceStarted with mock.SecondsSinceStarted inside the Asserts - a silly error) then the test fails with:

  Expected: 1
  But was:  2

Comment: FFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUU... If I *run* the test it passes. If I *debug and step through* it fails. Must be evaluating the mock's properties in my locals window or something...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can intercept return values with the `.WhenCalled` method. Note that you still need to provide a value via the `.Return` method, however Rhino will simply ignore it if `ReturnValue` is altered from the method invocation:

```
int invocationsCounter = 1;
const int IgnoredReturnValue = 10;
mock.Expect(m => m.SecondsSinceLifetime)
    .WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = invocationsCounter++)
    .Return(IgnoredReturnValue);

Assert.That(mock.SecondsSinceLifetime, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(mock.SecondsSinceLifetime, Is.EqualTo(2));
```

---

Digging around a bit more, it seems that `.Repeat.Once()` **does** indeed work in this case and can be used to achieve the same result:

```
mock.Expect(m => m.SecondsSinceStarted).Return(1).Repeat.Once();
mock.Expect(m => m.SecondsSinceStarted).Return(2).Repeat.Once();
mock.Expect(m => m.SecondsSinceStarted).Return(3).Repeat.Once();
```

Will return 1, 2, 3 on consecutive calls.

Comment: As I understand, for something other than sequential numbers he should create array and return values by index?

Comment: I agree that this method works, but this is essentially the same as having to implement a state machine, which I mentioned I am trying to avoid (i.e. if I wanted to return 11 on the second call, then I'd need to do something like "if (invocationsCounter == 1) return 1; else if (invocationsCounter == 2) return 11;" which looks very much like a state machine.

Comment: Re: your edit. Not sure if this is some functionality that has changed in the version of RhinoMocks that I am using and the one you are using, but I have run the test that is in my original question, and can tell you it fails (i.e. the first call to SecondsSinceStarted returns 2). Have you got a link to where you found that it does work?

Comment: Seems the problem was carelessness on my part - test passes if I run, but fails if I step through, probably evaluating the property for a watch window somewhere. Answer accepted, ta.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use

```
mock.Expect(m=>m.SecondsSinceStarted).Return(1).Repeat.Once();
mock.Expect(m=>m.SecondsSinceStarted).Return(2).Repeat.Once();
```

This will return `1` during the first call, and `2` during the second call. At least in Rhino Mocks 3.6.0.0.

Comment: This certainly conflicts with what I see when I run the test above

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer, this is correct, my test was only failing as I was stepping through and evaluating something inadvertently. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If time is the determining factor in what the method returns, I would try to abstract out the time passage so you have direct control over it in your tests.

Something like an interface called ITimeProvider with a member called GetElapsedTime() and then create a default implementation to use throughout your application.

Then when you are testing, pass in a mocked ITimeProvider so you control what is perceived by your application to be time passed.

Comment: Really, the time thing was just a handy example without fully describing what it is i'm trying to test. Even so, though, if I wanted to mock an ITimeProvider, which had a GetElapsedTime() method, the problem would still exist if I wanted to write a unit test which called GetElapsedTime() twice, and wanted my mock ITimeProvider to return a different time for each call.

Comment: Could you have the ITimeProvider be a property dependancy? Thus being able to inject new mocks before each call? Even so, if its not time you're dealing with, my answer is probably worthless...

Comment: My question was more about whether RhinoMocks supports this kind of interaction with generated mocks/stubs, and less about how I might work around it, should it not be supported. Thanks though.