# Rhino Mocks - How Do You Mock 5 Calls

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have 5 calls to a particular method and I wanted to return different things for each of those 5 calls.  I wanted some way in Rhino Mocks to say

```
For the 1st call return this
For the 2nd call return that
```

and so on

Is this possible?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Rhino mocks, but I believe during the "record" phase you just call it 5 times, specifying the desired value for each call... then in the "replay" phase it will do the right thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720908/rhinomocks-mocking-a-method-whose-return-value-changes-even-when-passed-the-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Repeat.Once()` after each method stub. For example:

```
myMock.Stub(x => x.Method()).Return(1).Repeat.Once()
myMock.Stub(x => x.Method()).Return(2).Repeat.Once()
```