# Proper Way to Test a file method with .net

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nunit

I'm new to .net and testing. My following code looks like this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
    public class AnimalXmlService
    {
        public Animal GetAnimalInfoFromXml(string url) {
            XElement xml_doc = GetXmlInfo(url);
            if (xml_doc == null)
            {
                return null;
            } else { 
                XElement animal_info = xml_doc.Element("Animal");
                string animal_name = GetAnimalName(animal_info);
                int animal_id = GetAnimalId(animal_info);

                return new Animal(animal_id, animal_name);
            }
        }

        private XElement GetXmlInfo(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                XElement animal_xml_info = XElement.Load(url);
                return animal_xml_info;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }


        private int GetAnimalName(XElement animal_info)
        {
           ....
        }

}
```

My question is how do I stub the `GetAnimalInfoFromXml` to return a file? I have the sample xml file that I will be using instead of making a request. Here's my following test. I'm also wondering if there are better ways to refactor this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace AnimalXmlService
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class AnimalXmlTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void extracts_valid_name()
        {
           //get xml file?

            animalService AnimalXmlService = new AnimalXmlService();
            name = animalService.GetAnimalName(xml_file);
            Assert.AreEqual(name, "bobby the tiger");
        }

        [Test]
        public void extracts_valid_id()
        {
           //get xml file?
           xml_file = fetch_file //is this appropriate?

            animalService AnimalXmlService = new AnimalXmlService();
            id = animalService.GetAnimalId(xml_file);
            Assert.AreEqual(name, "2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918281/why-cant-i-change-the-return-value-in-a-rhino-mocks-stub-object  
 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720908/rhinomocks-mocking-a-method-whose-return-value-changes-even-when-passed-the-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situations you can use test doubles.
First , you should make your codes more testable ( Breaking dependency )

```
public class AnimalXmlService
{
    private readonly IXmlReader _xmlReader;

    public AnimalXmlService(IXmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        this._xmlReader = xmlReader;
    }

    public Animal GetAnimalInfoFromXml(string url)
    {
        XElement xml_doc = _xmlReader.Load(url);
        if (xml_doc == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            XElement animal_info = xml_doc.Element("Animal");
            string animal_name = GetAnimalName(animal_info);
            int animal_id = GetAnimalId(animal_info);

            return new Animal(animal_id, animal_name);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you should create a stub to replace your real dependency. ( Also you can use frameworks like NSubstitute,Mock,...)

```
public class XmlReaderStub : IXmlReader
{
    public XElement XElement { get; set; }

    public XElement Load(string url)
    {
        return XElement;
    }
}
```

And finally

```
public class AnimalXmlTest
{
        [Test]
        public void extracts_valid_name()
        {
            var stub = new XmlReaderStub();
            stub.XElement = new XElement(); // some XElement
            animalService AnimalXmlService = new AnimalXmlService(stub);

            name = animalService.GetAnimalName();

            Assert.AreEqual(name, "bobby the tiger");
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks! where do you think is the best place I should add the xmlReaderstub?

Comment: where is the xml file in the AnimalXmlTest?

Comment: You should add XmlReaderStub in your Test Project.

Comment: I ended up doing something slightly different but the breaking dependency thing got me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have another method in your class like the one below which returns an XmlDocument.

```
 public XmlDocument GetXmlFile()
   {      
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.LoadXml("<Animal><Name>Bobby the tiger</Name></Animal>");

      return doc;
   }
```